# How to build a table within select under WITH in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Maybe a stupid question but how can we build a very small helper table with a SELECT in BigQuery?

The use case is that sometimes I want to create a really simple table with 3 rows and 3 columns for example. I don't want to have a persistent table in BQ, I don't want to use CREATE TEMP TABLE... I just want to start my query with WITH, create small helper table a then run the main query combining bigger proper BQ tables and the small helper table.

The helper table would look like this:
date | sales | cost
2020-01-15 | 10 | 10
2020-01-16 | 10 | 10

Currently, I usually create an array and then I have to unnest it + do some SPLIT() to convert it into a table format and that's quite painful...

Thx!

Comment: If you are looking just create a table with _**WITH**_, you can have a look at the syntax in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I just want to start my query with WITH, create small helper table a then run the main query

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL and might look as silly as question is  - but that is what SO is for - right?

```
#standardSQL
WITH helper_table AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-01-15' dt_date, 10 sales, 10 cost UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-01-16', 10, 10
)
SELECT *
FROM helper_table
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail,
Hmm...interesting idea, I think this will do the job for me.

It should have some to my mind.

Thx!